# Can the .loc command be used with groupby's apply function

Tags: python, pandas

This question already has answers here:
Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column (13 answers)
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If that question doesn’t answer your issue, edit your question to highlight the difference between the associated question and yours. If edited, your question will be reviewed and might be reopened.

Find out more about duplicates and why your question has been closed.

Closed yesterday.

Hi. I have a DataFrame with multiple columns where I have successfully assigned values in a new column (sent_inclination) given a condition. However, I want to change the output such that the values are given to the entire given group identified by the column "id". The condition is: if "freq_cent" > 0.5, then the new column should have the value from the column 'Sentiment' in it for the given id. That is whether the freq_cent is greater than 0.5 or less than 0.5 for a given observation, the new column should contain the sentiment value that qualifies for greater than 0.5 for that entire group.
I am able to assign values to the entire DataFrame but cannot make sure that the values are the same for the entire group.

Here is my sample DataFrame:

```
data = {'id': ['205', '205', '204', '204', '204'], 
         'Sentiment': ['Positive', 'Positive', 'Neutral', 'Positive', 'Positive']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['freq'] = df.groupby('Sentiment')['id'].transform(pd.Series.nunique)
df['freq_sum'] = df.groupby('id')['freq'].transform(pd.Series.count)
df['freq_cent'] = (df['freq']/df['freq_sum'])
```

where if I apply the code:

```
df['sent_inclination'] = df.loc[df['freq_cent'] >0.5, ['Sentiment']]
```

I get the output:

```
    id  Sentiment   freq    freq_sum    freq_cent   sent_inclination
0   205 Positive    2       2           1.000000    Positive
1   205 Positive    2       2           1.000000    Positive
2   204 Neutral     1       3           0.333333    NaN
3   204 Positive    2       3           0.666667    Positive
4   204 Positive    2       3           0.666667    Positive
```

The desired output should have 'sent_inclination' as Positive for all observations where id is 204, that is:

```
    id  Sentiment   freq    freq_sum    freq_cent   sent_inclination
0   205 Positive    2       2           1.000000    Positive
1   205 Positive    2       2           1.000000    Positive
2   204 Neutral     1       3           0.333333    Positive
3   204 Positive    2       3           0.666667    Positive
4   204 Positive    2       3           0.666667    Positive
```

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Unfortunately the groupby.filter method doesn't work for me.

So far I have tried multiple codes, some of which are as follows:

```
df['sent_inclination'] = df.loc[df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: df.loc[df['freq_cent'] >0.5, df['Sentiment']])]

df['sent_inclination'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: (df.query('freq_cent >0.5')['Sentiment']))

df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['sent_inclination'] == x['Sentiment'] if (x['freq_cent'] > 0.5) else '')

df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['sent_inclination'] == (df.query('freq_cent >0.5')['Sentiment']))
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a place for homework

Comment: It is not homework. I am stuck on a code and would like some help. I have tried to apply the groupby commands that are in similar questions but it is not working. I have posted a well explained question with a sample dataframe, as it expected. That is probably why it seems like a homework question.

Comment: @PV8. Homework is allowed if the OP proved he makes an effort to solve their problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with my failed codes.

Comment: You can try `df.sort_values('freq_cent', ascending=False).groupby('id')['Sentiment'].transform('first')`. What happens if for a group id you have 0.33 (Positive), 0.33 (Neutral) and 0.33 (Negative)?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! this outputs NaN for the third row, same as when I used df['sent_inclination'] = df.loc[df['freq_cent'] >0.5, ['Sentiment']]. I would like the entire group to get the selected sent_inclination.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `groupby`from `pandas` und `where`from numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#this will get you a appended dataframe where the maximum per group is picked (you can also use "mean" instead of "max" to get the group average
df = pd.merge(df, df.groupby(['id'])['freq_cent'].max().reset_index(), on='id', how='left')

#this will check the value is greater then 0,5
df['sent_inclination'] = np.where(df['freq_cent_y'] >0.5, 'Positive', df['Sentiment'])

#cleaning and rename
df.rename(columns={"freq_cent_x": "freq_cent_x"}, inplace=True)
df = df[['id', 'freq', 'freq_sum', 'freq_cent_x', 'sent_inclination']]
```

output:

```
print(df)
   id  freq  freq_sum  freq_cent_x sent_inclination
0  205     2         2     1.000000         Positive
1  205     2         2     1.000000         Positive
2  204     1         3     0.333333         Positive
3  204     2         3     0.666667         Positive
4  204     2         3     0.666667         Positive
```

Based on the condition you can also adjust it, simple change the line with `np.where`:

```
df['sent_inclination'] = np.where(df['freq_cent_y'] >0.5, 'Positive', np.where(df['freq_cent_y' <0.33, 'Negative', 'Neutral'))
```

would give a outcome where >0.5  is "Positive", between 0.5 and 0.33 "Neutral", and <0.33 "Negative"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! the code works, however in my bigger dataset the value that should be getting chosen is not necessarily Positive. Therefore, this part df['sent_inclination'] = np.where(df['freq_cent_y'] >0.5, 'Positive', df['Sentiment'])
will not always assign the correct value. Is there anyway to automate this?

Comment: does the edit help you?

Comment: I don't always have the same order in the assignment of categories, so it is possible that >0.5 is not positive but is rather another category. This is why I asked about an automated assigned, i.e., whatever category is above >0.5 for the given id, then that category should be assigned as the preferred inclination for that given id everywhere.